# How to know if a record DOESN'T exists on a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, rows

I'm dealing whit this for a couple of hours and I can't find the way to get the answer.

I've a table with a maximun of 4 records for a product (let's call it that way) for a diferent period (column name with a number). I'm trying to return the ones that DO NOT has a particular type of CONSUMPTION_TYPE_ID. But it doesn't work.

I'll explain it simple. I've a table with these fields (there are more, but these one are just fine)

```
    product_id - CONSUMPTION_TYPE_ID - consumption_period
    123              103                   1
    123              104                   1
    123              107                   1
    123              108                   1
```

I need to return the ones that don't has one particular type of consumption, let's say that the type 107 is missing (the row doesn't exists), the select query should show the other 3 or any present. I don't mind doing the same select 4 times, I could also try to do a cursor for it and use loop to check every one. The point is, that the type of query with "not in" or "not exists" doesn't work. It gives me a result like the one given below, but when I query the "consumption_period" it shows me the missing "CONSUMPTION_TYPE_ID" and that's because the "not in" clause it's only hidding the results.

```
    this is what I need.
    select * from t1 where CONSUMPTION_TYPE_ID != 108;

    product_id - CONSUMPTION_TYPE_ID - consumption_period
    123              103                   1
    123              104                   1
    123              107                   1
```

I hope you can help me with this. I'm stucked, it maybe simple, but I'm having one of those stucked times. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What makes this such a bad question is that you're explaining your requirements by what you DON'T want. Please show the desired results, instead of the undesired results.

Comment: but that's obvious man, i want the oppossite to it!, if I have baskets with 4 fruits and I  want to see the one that don't have  apples it would show me that. I need to see the ones that DO NOT have the apples, that way I can fix that problem by adding apples to the basket. Thanks! ;)

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's obvious to you, but the idea is to make it obvious for us.

Comment: I guess I'm answering you with the example. I know it can be tricky, sort of, but that's why I'm asking this. I also know that searching for things that don't exists it's worse that the things that do exists. Thanks bro.

Comment: I'm still puzzled as to why you refuse to simply add the desired result set to your question. It should be a trivial task if you know what you want to achieve. However, I undeleted my previous answer with a slight modification, even though I'm still not sure if this is what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should've posted that `NOT EXISTS` query that doesn't work, because that is the right way to do this.

If I got your requirements right: all products that do not have a record for a specific consumption_type_id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM t1 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM t1
WHERE t.product_id = product_id
AND Consumption_Type_ID = ?)
```

Comment: See this is what I was trying to do, the main goal was for me to show those records. I'm testing it now, and, my query wasn't so different from yours in the last test, not gettin' the results I've wanted but close.

I can thank you now because I was missing a condition, wasn't matching the "product_id". I'll comeback if this works and mark your answer right.

Comment: That was right. Marked as good. And, thanks! this site helps so much with your answers!

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer here is to search for `CONSUMPTION_TYPE_ID = 108` and have the surrounding code check for a lack of rows, rather than the existence of rows.

If you really need a row return for each `consumption_type_id` that's not in this table, then you should probably be selecting from the lookup table for `consumption_type_id`:

```
select *
from consumption_type ct
where not exists (select * 
                  from t1 
                  where t1.consumption_type_id = ct.consumption_type_id)
and ct.consumption_type_id = 108
```

Comment: Thanks Allan, I've done that already. That's the main reason for me to ask a question here.

Comment: I wrote a lot but i lost changes LOL. Anyway, it doesn't work that way. I'm trying to identify the ones that do not have the rows, because they need to be fixed (every period should have 4 types of consumption).
If I equal the results to one in specific, it would hide the results bringin' me up those who match the criteria 'cause there's more than 1 type of consumption. Thanks again Allan!